# Moment Js changes time in timezone object even when system timezone is same to supplied timezone

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I'm using moment js for timezone conversions.

```
moment.tz("2017-09-04 1:48 PM", "Asia/Calcutta").format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm A");
```

Moment js converting the time  `2017-09-04 1:48 PM` to `04-09-2017 19:18 PM` while the system is in same timezone `Asia/Calcutta`.

How to solve this.

[image]

My system timezone is `Asia/Calcutta` . Used `moment.tz.guess();` to get the exact timezone value.

`moment.tz("2017-09-04 1:48 PM", moment.tz.guess()).format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm A");`

this also changes the time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input is not ISO 8601 compliant format, you should add `"YYYY-MM-DD h:mm A"` format parameter when parsing it.

Your code gives *Deprecation Warning*, so you have to use [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) parsing method as suggested in the [parsing guide](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/).

Here a working sample:

```js
var m = moment.tz("2017-09-04 1:48 PM", "YYYY-MM-DD h:mm A", "Asia/Calcutta").format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm A");
console.log( m );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.13/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```